# Get first 3 digits of NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

```
float distance = 2347293874923;
NSNumber * dist = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
```

How to get only first 3 digits of dist in a NSString.

Comment: For 1.234 & 0.1234, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
float distance = 2347293874923;
NSString * n = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distance];
NSString * s = [n substringToIndex:3];

NSLog(@"%@", s);
```